# Analytical proof required $\binom{n}{r} < (n+1)^r$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, solution-verification, binomial-coefficients, relations

$\binom{n}{r} < (n+1)^r$

I need help to prove the above expression using some analytical method.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? ${ n \choose r } < n^r / r! < (n+1)^r$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment but some analytical way to say this thing.

Comment: Can you define "analytical method"?

Comment: May be few logical mathematical steps. I know it's obvious but to say in few logical steps. Try to convince a stubborn student in mathematical language.

Comment: Do you mean "use words and not math"? Please define "analytical method", because otherwise it suggests you want someone to use analysis to solve (as opposed to algebraic or combinatorial methods).

Comment: May be your relationship is suffice thanks. It will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}<\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}=\underbrace{n(n-1)\dots(n-r+1)}_{r-terms}<\underbrace{(n+1)(n+1)\dots(n+1)}_{r-terms}=(n+1)^r$$

Comment: Ty Jensen Thanks very nice explanation.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} = \frac{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}k}{r!\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-r}k} = \frac{\prod\limits_{k=n-r+1}^{n}k}{r!} \le \frac{\prod\limits_{k=n-r+1}^{n}n}{r!} = \frac{n^r}{r!} \le n^r \le \sum\limits_{k=0}^{r} \binom{r}{k} n^k = (n+1)^r
$$

Comment: Thanks thinkingeye nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Equality holds at $r = 0$, so inequality starts at $r = 1.$

Simplifying assumption made that $2 \leq n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ and that $r \in \{1,2,\cdots, n\}.$

With base case of $r=1$ established, do induction on $r$, noting the scaling factor on each side of the inequality.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.